# Is there connectedReleaseAndroidTest gradle task?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I have 2 flavors of my application: paid and free.
I have 2 build types: debug and release.

When I issue `gradlew` tasks I get, among other things:

**connectedFreeDebugAndroidTest** - Installs and runs the tests for freeDebug on connected devices.

**connectedPaidDebugAndroidTest** - Installs and runs the tests for paidDebug on connected devices.

But I do **not** get 
**connectedFreeReleaseAndroidTest** neither **connectedPaidReleaseAndroidTest**.

However, there are for example: **testFreeReleaseUnitTest**, **installFreeRelease** and other such tasks dealing with release build type. But no testing tasks for the release build type.

Why is that?

In my `build.gradle` I have:

```
androidTestCompile ('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:+')
androidTestCompile ('com.android.support.test:runner:+')
```

and also `release` type only in `buildTypes`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your build.gradle, add:

```
android {
  testBuildType "release"
}
```

Comment: Can we make testBuildType conditional ? Means for debug build, it will executes test cases on debug build and for release build, it will executes test cases on release build.